# WCF service Single proxy instance with multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I developed a WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service which would send a request to the thirdparty webservice and expects a response.So all i would be given is the url/wsdl information of the thirdparty service where its hosted.

I want to implement say a test service which would give response to my request and Create a single proxy of that service by adding service reference in the visual studio to the actual service.So there can be any number of third party applications which would provide their urls in the future for communication.

My question about the WCF is can i create a single proxy client once and just send the request to a webservice based on the url on the fly ? Is it possible to use the same proxy client for both HTTP and HTTPS by just passing the binding and address parameters dyanmically ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have create the proxy you cannot change its address. You could have several open proxies, one per 3rd party. In addition a single proxy cannot be reused for http and https since they use different bindings (in addition to the reason above).

One reason for this behavior (which may or may not be relevant in your case) id that proxy can keep state with the server, for example an open security session.

Comment: I am finally able to understand how wcf works.So I was trying to use the channelfactory and able to send the request to the 3rd party service.But again I am struck at calling the channel where i have to pass the contract information in the channel for various endpoints.Is there way i can just pass the service name from the endpoint of config file through channel factory ?

Comment: not sure what you mean. when you create the channel you need to pass the contract. if instead you generate a proxy via "add service reference" and instantiate it then you can give just the name from the config as a string